# How do I add a service to Terminal's "New Remote Connection" window?

Tags: macos, terminal

In Terminal, pressing Shift+Command+K opens the "New Remote Connection" dialog box, which includes SSH, SFTP, FTP, and Telnet in the Service list and all Back-To-My-Mac systems in the Server list.

How can I add another Service, for example [Mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/), to the list?

### System

- OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.2
- Macbook Air

  - 13-inch, Mid 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the answer had been on the screen all along. There's a + button under both the Services side and the Servers side. You can add to both.

[image: Screenshot of adding a service to Mac OS Terminal]